# Infering the hash algorithm from input and output

Tags: cryptography

Say we have an image named `907251651.jpg`. This image is on a webpage for a unique species, which can be uniquely identified by either its taxon id `165121`, or its scientific name `Lycopodium madeirense`.
I have reasons to believe that the name of the image is computed based on either the taxon id or the species name (though I can't be sure).
Is there any way to infer how the image name might be computed ?

Comment: There _may_ be but it would be difficult to do that on such a small sample size (one item).  Additionally, I'm not convinced that the function would be described a hashing algorithm (although this is an opinion only).  Also it seems unrelated to cryptography which the question has been tagged with.

Comment: @Martin Would you suggest another tag instead ? and what sample size would be workable ?